# How to save a birthday date in iOS 5 programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios7, contacts

I saved birthday date in iphone contact in ios 7 but the code not working in ios 5. Any other way make it?

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
NSDate * birdayDate =[dateFormat dateFromString:contactCardBirthdateLbl.text];

NSArray * nameArray = [contactCardNameLbl.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty,(__bridge CFTypeRef)([nameArray objectAtIndex:0]) , nil);
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty,(__bridge CFTypeRef)([nameArray objectAtIndex:1]), nil);
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonJobTitleProperty,(__bridge CFTypeRef) contactCardOccupationLbl.text, nil);
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonBirthdayProperty,(__bridge CFDateRef)birdayDate,nil);
```

Comment: have you check your date is not null?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a birthdate to a contact (through the Contacts app) with only a month/day..

Check this,

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();

  NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
    NSDate * birdayDate =[dateFormat dateFromString:contactCardBirthdateLbl.text];

    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM"];
    //don't set year in address book (yyyy=1604)


    NSDate *bdate=[formatter dateFromString:[formatter stringFromDate:birdayDate]];

NSArray * nameArray = [contactCardNameLbl.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty,(__bridge CFTypeRef)([nameArray objectAtIndex:0]) , nil);
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty,(__bridge CFTypeRef)([nameArray objectAtIndex:1]), nil);
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonJobTitleProperty,(__bridge CFTypeRef) contactCardOccupationLbl.text, nil);
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonBirthdayProperty,(__bridge CFDateRef)bdate,nil);
```